# Problem with integer bounds and some if else

Tags: java

I have been working on a fun coding project for class and then I tried some if else statements and some bounds for integers and everything fell apart from there. Please help. I tried changing the sections to make sure that the bounds work but they never do and when I run the code no matter what numbers I use it always shows up to be underweight when a 300 pound 60 inches was plugged in or any other number.

```
System.out.println("Welcome to the BMI calculator portion!");
System.out.println("Lets begin!");
int bodyWeight;
System.out.println("Please enter your body wight in pounds here: ");
bodyWeight = input.nextInt();
int height;
System.out.println("Please enter your height here in inches: ");
height = input.nextInt();

//This part will convert pounds to kilograms
double kiloGram = bodyWeight / 2.205;

// This part will convert inches to cm
double centimeters = height * 2.54;

//This part will calculate the bmi using the BMI equation
double bmiResult = kiloGram / (centimeters * centimeters);

// This part will see the correlation of BMI to healthiness
if (bmiResult < 18.5) {
    y = "you are underweight according to your BMI.";
}
double bmiResults = 0;
if (bmiResults >= 18.5 && bmiResults <= 24.9) {
    y = "you are nomal weight according to your BMI.";
}
if (bmiResult >= 25 && bmiResults <= 29.5) {
    y = "you are overweight according to your BMI.";
}
if (bmiResults >= 30) {
    y = "you are obese according to you BMI.";
}
// this part will release the info about how the bmi worked
System.out.println("Congratulations, " + y);

//This part will give the user a summary of today's activity

System.out.println("Here is your result for today!");
System.out.println("You had " +breakfastCal+ " calories for breakfast today.");
System.out.println("You had " +lunchCal+ " calories for lunch today.");
System.out.println("You had " +dinnerCal+ " calories for dinner today.");
System.out.println("You had " +snackCal+ " calories for snack today.");
System.out.println("Your total caloric intake today was " +totalCal+ " calories, " +x);
System.out.println("For the BMI portion:");
System.out.println("You entered that you are " +bodyWeight+ " pounds, and " +height+ " inches.");
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: You have `double bmiResults = 0;`, which you never set anything else to, note the `s` at the end compared to `double bmiResult = kiloGram / (centimeters * centimeters);` without a trailing `s`.

Comment: The  code is correct apart from the typo with the variable and the formula. It is using centimeter instead of meter.

Comment: General note: debug your code and use a proper IDE which would make it clear that you have two variables, that are used strangely, most IDEs should mark all `bmiResults` `if`s as "always false" since the value is always zero.

Comment: *FYI:* Don't use `x <= 24.9` and `x >= 25`, because what if value is 24.95? Instead, use `x < 25`

Comment: i think your formula might be wrong, it is meter squared not centimeter squared

Answer (score 1):

With all the statements made in the comments we may have enough to warrant an answer. So sum it up

- you have two mismatched variables
- you have a faulty bmi formula
- you have non exhaustive if statements

Fixed code:

```
//This part will convert pounds to kilograms
double kiloGram = bodyWeight / 2.205;

// This part will convert inches to cm
double meters = height * 2.54 / 100; // <-- we care about the height in meters

//This part will calculate the bmi using the BMI equation
double bmiResult = kiloGram / (meters * meters); // <-- only one bmiResult variable

// This part will see the correlation of BMI to healthiness
if (bmiResult < 18.5) {
    y = "you are underweight according to your BMI.";
} else if (bmiResult <= 25) { // <-- more concise if + else if
    y = "you are nomal weight according to your BMI.";
} else if (bmiResult <= 30) {
    y = "you are overweight according to your BMI.";
} else {
    y = "you are obese according to you BMI.";
}
```